# Angular2: Calling other functions inside call back functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular, asynccallback

I am building an Angular2 application.
I have an asynchronous function `deleteObject` in `myService`. It returns a Promise. I have another function in the Component called `refresh`, which refreshes the page. How do I call refresh from inside the Promise. This is what I tried:

```
export class AppComponent{

    refresh(){
        // refresh page here
    }

    delete(){
        this.myService.deleteObject(params).then(
           function(data){
             //this.refresh() doesn't work here.
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are coding in Typescript, you can use [fat arrow functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) instead.   They keep the `this` context you would expect.  So replace

```
delete(){
        this.myService.deleteObject(params).then(
           function(data){
             //this.refresh() doesn't work here.
        });
}
```

With this:

```
delete(){
    this.myService.deleteObject(params).then(
            (data)=>{
                //this.refresh() should work here
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I think this is the right answer, when it comes to Typescript. :)

Answer (score 1):

this is a context issue. "this" refers to the callback function's context, which could be the promise or something. what you actually want is a reference to the component context, you can achieve that like so

```
delete(){
    var componentRef = this; // colloquially "that" or "self"
    this.myService.deleteObject(params).then(
       function(data){
         componentRef.refresh() // does work here.
    });
}
```

Comment: also fwiw, you could look into [rxjs observables](http://blog.angular-university.io/functional-reactive-programming-for-angular-2-developers-rxjs-and-observables/) which is a powerful angular paradigm (technically rxjs paradigm, but they incorporate it)

Comment: Thanks @kirinthos. I am new to Javascript. It worked for me. :)

Comment: @UnderWood might i suggest giving [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) a read

Comment: Thank @kirinthos. I will take a look at it.